# How to set locale in postgres using docker-compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, dockerfile, locale

I've tried multiple ways of changing the locale to en_GB and nothing seems to work.

My current `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      PGDATA: ${PGDATA}
      # LANG: 'en_GB.UTF-8'

  adminer:
    depends_on: 
      - db
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  
volumes:
  pg-data:
```

An official postgres image docs says to create a `Dockerfile` with:

```
FROM postgres
RUN localedef -i en_GB -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_GB.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_GB.utf8
```

However this has no effect whatsoever.. Tried setting enviorment variable LC_* and LANG however this throws build error of enviorment variables being configured wrong.

Having just a `Dockerfile` without the enviorment variables set container builds and db is being reinitialized but while running first migration with `knex` the table consisting `money` type is still in dollars.

Comment: You can confirm that you have created the `Dockerfile` as indicated and **replaced** the _image_ tag on your docker-compose.yml with your newly built image?

Comment: Could you explain? As what I did for every try I run docker compose down -v and rm -rf postgres named volume to start clear. Docs recommend to put Dockerfile in the root where the docker-compose.yml is. I did specified the build context as root and pointed it to a Dockerfile too. Should the image have explicitly specified version eg. postgres: 9.3 in both compose file and Dockerfile?

Comment: You say that you have created the Dockerfile above, you should then replace the tag _image: postgres_ with the image created from the Dockerfile, or alternatively you must replace the _image_ tag with _build_

Comment: Although the documentation says otherwise, I was able to use the `LANG` line in an **Alpine** based image after adding `RUN apk add --no-cache musl-locales musl-locales-lang` in the dockerfile. I’m not sure if it’s complete, but maybe this works for you too?